# Only get post types based on support

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type-support

I am trying to retrieve a list including both builtin and custom post types:

```
$post_types = get_post_types(array(
  'public' => TRUE,
), 'objects');
```

The above almost works, but I would like to exclude the `attachment` from this list, only returning post types with specific support such as `editor`, `title` and `thumbnail`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that [`get_post_types_by_support()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types_by_support/) seems to be the solution to get the desired result:

```
$post_types = get_post_types_by_support(array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'));
```

The above will return `post`, `page` and any custom post type that supports `title`, `editor` and `thumbnail`.

Since this will also return private post types, we could loop through the list and check if the type is viewable at the frontend. This can be done by using the [`is_post_type_viewable()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_viewable/) function:

```
foreach ($post_types as $key => $post_type) {
  if (!is_post_type_viewable($post_type)) {
    unset($post_types[$post_type]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: this will work in *most*  cases.

Answer (score 4):

[`get_post_types()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) accepts an array of arguments to match the fields of a [post type object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/). So, you could do something like this (not tested):

```
$post_types = get_post_types(array(
  'public'   => true,
  'supports' => array( 'editor', 'title', 'thumbnail' )
), 'objects');
```

Unfortunately, you can not set someting like "exclude" in this function, and also you get only post types that support **exactly** `'editor', 'title', 'thumbnail'`, no more and no less.

Or you could use `get_post_types_by_support()` (only for WP 4.5 and greater. Also, note that you can not exclude specific post types with this function either, but for the specific case of support for `editor, title, thumbnail`, attachment post type will be excluded in *most* cases).

```
$post_types = get_post_types_by_support( array( 'editor', 'title', 'thumbnail' ) );
```

If you want something that will work in any case, I would try to get post types based in a wider criteria, then build your own array, something like this:

```
$_post_types = get_post_types_by_support( array( 'editor', 'title', 'thumbnail' ) );

$post_types = [];

foreach($_post_types as $post_type) {
    // In most cases, attachment post type won't be here, but it can be
    if( $post_type->name !== 'attachment' ) {
        $post_types[] = $post_type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `supports` does not seem to work? I have a custom post type that supports `editor` and if I use `supports => array('editor')` I get an empty result? You second approach seems to work though.

Comment: It seems like we could use `get_post_types_by_support()` support to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach for the OP's question would be to just unset 'attachment' from the returned array;

```
$post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => TRUE,), 'objects');
unset($post_types['attachment']);
```

While not as elegant as the other solutions it has the least overhead.